# How to revert from apps corner?

Tags: apps-corner

I own Lumia 620 and while going through the settings, I turned on the apps corner. And now I am not able to revert since my phone's power key doesnt work. Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, to get out of Apps Corner, you'd press and hold the Power button, and then swipe right.

If your power button is defective, you may need to pull the battery out